# Karate-Jenkins- ERROR com.intuit.karate - . getting this error only when i run from jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins, karate

iam running my karate code from Jenkins. where ia, getting below error.

ERROR com.intuit.karate - evaluation of 'karate-config.js' failed: javascript function call failed: ReferenceError: "karate" is not defined .

karate config file keeps on running.

iam using mvn test command to run the job.. even I have tried in Jenkins machine and mvn command works. only in through Jenkins iam getting issue.

Comment: I'm having the same issue - were you able to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Try to upgrade java version in Jenkins server.